# Matching a value in the row using a OR operator in pl/sql block

Tags: regex, plsql

There is a column that contains values 
like

```
ID_1 '1999|12241|1485988|2470|12731|1486125|999|12730|1485312|1485359|2468|12729|1485266|1485313|2467'
ID_2 '1485988|12241|1999|2470|12731|1486125|999|12730|1485312|1485359|2468|12729|1485266|1485313|2467'
```

I have to match them

```
case
when instr(column_name,''1999|')>0 ----if it is in the beginning.
then column_name like ''1999||%'
when instr(column_name,''1999||')=0 
then column_name like '%|'1999|'--- if the value is in the end.
```

But how to find the values that are in the middle.
And the major concern is the same value can be present in middle in one row and in the end in another row. Both needs
to be considered.

I tried using 'OR' operator. its time consuming.

```
select * from table_name where column_name like ('%|1999') or column_name like  ('%|1999|%') or column_name like  ('1999|%');
```

Should I redefine my approach.

Comment: You should change the way you're storing values in the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with only one like, if you add `|` before and after

```
select * from table_name 
 where '|'||column_name||'|' like  ('%|1999|%') 
;
```

Simpler, not sure faster.

Hope it helps
J